# How to scroll to a particular element in Selenium WebDriver java with the Fixed header

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to scroll to the particular element using the below option and its working

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

but the problem is my page has the fixed header so the scrolled element was went under the header and its not clickable. Any suggestions to scroll to the element and make it clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `moveToElement(WebElement target, int xOffset, int yOffset)` from [Actions class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

```
int headrVerticalSize;
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element, 0, -1 * headrVerticalSize).Perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add some scrolling up to make element visible:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.querySelector('body').scrollTop-=100;");
```

You can set `scrollTop` value that suits you most